# Ubuntu Resolution issues (virtual machine)

Tags: display, display-resolution

I am new to Linux.  (like this-is-the-first-thing-I've-ever-really-done-in-Linux-at-all new, NEW new...)  I just created a new Hyper-V VM and installed Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS with GNOME 42.5.
When I connect to the server, the screen resolution is small.  Only 1024x768.  I'd really like more real estate to work with.

- I tried rt click / Display but there are no other values in the down except 1024x768.
- I tried messing with xrandr but it will not take any new settings.
- I tried editing /etc/default/grub to increase GFXMODE and add GFXPAYLOAD
- I tried using set-vmvideo Ubuntu -horizontalresolution:1440 -verticalresolution:900 -resolutiontype single
  There has GOT to be a better/faster/easier way - its a simple *(&^%*&^$%&% resolution change people!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have experience with Hyper-V, but I do have some using VMware, in which sometimes you need to install VMware tools, used to improve usability of the virtual machine. After doing a quick search on the internet I came across this:

For Hyper-V,

- in context of "Hyper-V Manager > host > Hyper-V Settings > Enhanced Session Mode", Check the box of "Use enhanced session mode";
- in context of "Hyper-V Manager > vm > Settings > Integration Services", Check all the boxes, including "Guest services".

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/341631/how-to-adjust-virtual-machine-display-resolution-t.html

Comment: If this was useful to you, please consider tagging this answer as the solution, it will help the community and me, thanks.